# Probability with marbles and dice

Tags: probability

1. A bag contains 6 white, 3 black, 4 red, 6 yellow, and 5 green marbles. If you reach in and choose a marble at random, what is the probability that it is yellow?
2. If you are playing a game that has a pair of dice you have to roll, what is the probability that the sum of the numbers you roll will be a three?

Comment: How do I know how many outcomes there are??

Comment: for the marbles question, it is okay to imagine each marble as having both a color **and a number**.  The outcomes then can be thought of as $\{w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,b1,b2,b3,r1,r2,r3,r4,\dots\}$.  Each of those outcomes can be seen to be (*or at least assumed to be*) equally likely.  As for the dice, imagine one of the dice is red and the other is blue.  The possible outcomes are then $\{(r1,b1),(r1,b2),(r1,b3),\dots,(r6,b5),(r6,b6)\}$.  Assuming the dice are fair and rolls are independent, each of those are again equally likely.  Note the sum of the dice depends on what were rolled.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

For both items, compute:

1. How many outcomes are there for you to call the test a success?
2. How many outcomes are there in total?
3. $$\mathbb{P}[\text{success}] = \frac{\text{# success outcomes}}{\text{# total outcomes}}$$

Comment: disclaimer: line 3 describing probability is only valid in "*equiprobable sample spaces*" and would not be valid if the dice were loaded/unfair or if the green marbles were slippery and difficult to grab etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz +1, indeed, but it seems overkill for the OP with such a simple question...